# how to change ipset set type?

Tags: ipset

I have an ipset in-use for my firewall.  It was created using set-type "nethash".  Turns-out this list will only contain individual ip addresses, making set-type "iphash" more efficient (per man page, anyway).

I tried swapping the current list with a new one with the correct set-type, but this is apparently not allowed.

I also tried deleting the current list to recreate it with the different settings, but it is in-use by my firewall (as it should be).

Is there a way to force --swap an ipset?  Or is there a way to change an existing set to a new set-type?  I haven't been able to find a way.

Thanks.